# What is the difference among apt-cache policy, apt-cache show, and apt-cache showpkg?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, version

**Note:** I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/412348/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-cache-show-and-apt-cache-showpkg) QnA addressing `apt-cache show` v/s `apt-cache showpkg` but couldn't find any QnA addressing the difference among all the three options i.e. `policy`, `show`, & `showpkg`.

For example, for a Google Chrome in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 
the output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable` :

```
google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 84.0.4147.105-1
  Candidate: 84.0.4147.135-1
  Version table:
     84.0.4147.135-1 500
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 84.0.4147.105-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `apt-cache show google-chrome-stable` command:

```
Package: google-chrome-stable
Version: 84.0.4147.135-1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
Installed-Size: 228519
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0)
Depends: 
.
.
Recommends: libu2f-udev, libvulkan1
Provides: www-browser
Priority: optional
Section: web
Filename: pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_84.0.4147.135-1_amd64.deb
Size: 69582256
SHA256: <sha256>
SHA1: <sha1>
MD5sum: <md5sum>
Description: The web browser from Google
 Google Chrome is a browser ... , and easier.
Description-md5: <md5>

Package: google-chrome-stable
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: web
Installed-Size: 229295
Maintainer: Chrome Linux Team <chromium-dev@chromium.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 84.0.4147.105-1
Provides: www-browser
Depends:
.
.
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.0)
Recommends: libu2f-udev, libvulkan1
Description: The web browser from Google
 Google Chrome is a browser ... , and easier.
Description-md5: <md5>
```

Output of `apt-cache showpkg google-chrome-stable` command:

```
Package: google-chrome-stable
Versions: 
84.0.4147.135-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: <md5>
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: <md5>

84.0.4147.105-1 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: <md5>
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/dpkg/status
                  MD5: <md5>


Reverse Depends: 
  goopg,google-chrome-stable
Dependencies: 
.
.
Provides: 
84.0.4147.135-1 - www-browser (= ) 
84.0.4147.105-1 - www-browser (= ) 
Reverse Provides:
```

So, apart from the difference among these three, my other queries are:

1. When should I use which one?
2. For `policy` & `showpkg` options, why it's showing two different versions i.e. `84.0.4147.105-1` & `84.0.4147.135-1`? Also, both of them are being printed in proper order. On the other, for the `show` option, it's gives details about `84.0.4147.135-1` and later on about `84.0.4147.105-1`. But, the amount of details as well as order among details is different. Why?
3. In `show` and `showpkg` options, most of the details are twice. Why?
4. When I checked the version of my Google Chrome using `google-chrome-stable --version` is showed `Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105`. So, why I'm getting `84.0.4147.135` as well while running `apt-cache` along with the above three options?

Answer (score 2):

The differences are described in [`man apt-cache`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-cache). In summary:

- `policy` shows priorities, either of all repositories, or of the packages given as arguments;
- `show` shows the main package information (all the information in the control files, without relying on any external information);
- `showpkg` shows forward and reverse dependencies.

1. You should use the command which gives the information you’re after. `policy` for example is useful to determine what versions are available and why they might or might not be installed.
2. All commands show information about all available versions: the currently-installed version (if any) and the versions in the repositories (as of the last `apt update`).
3. The details are repeated because there are two versions available.
4. The currently-installed version is 105, but 135 is available from the repositories. `policy` shows 135 as the candidate, so the next upgrade will try to install it.

Comment: Does `showpkg` show dependencies recursively? Because `show` also outputs `Depends:`, but `showpkg` output is longer and more complex to understand (IMO). E.g. now I see for `Dependencies:` `1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 -...` long line then `1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 - ...` and another two similar  lines. Why 4 lines with slightly different versions?